# CoreOS isn't automatically updating

Tags: coreos

I have a bunch of CoreOS machines installed from an ignition template, served via matchbox. The machines are running 1185.3.0, which is not the most recent stable release. They do not automatically update, though. I can manually trigger an update with `update_engine_client -check_for_update`, and they'll update correctly. Here's a log excerpt from the automatic update check:

```
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.101521 32226 prefs.cc:51] certificate-report-to-send-update not present in /var/lib/update_engine/prefs
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.101647 32226 prefs.cc:51] certificate-report-to-send-download not present in /var/lib/update_engine/prefs
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.102347 32226 omaha_request_params.cc:58] Current group set to stable
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.102634 32226 update_attempter.cc:465] Already updated boot flags. Skipping.
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.102658 32226 update_attempter.cc:608] Scheduling an action processor start.
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.102708 32226 action_processor.cc:36] ActionProcessor::StartProcessing: OmahaRequestAction
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.102998 32226 omaha_request_action.cc:245] Posting an Omaha request to https://public.update.core-os.net/v1/update/
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.103022 32226 omaha_request_action.cc:246] Request: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: <request protocol="3.0" version="CoreOSUpdateEngine-0.1.0.0" updaterversion="CoreOSUpdateEngine-0.1.0.0" installsource="scheduler" ismachine="1">
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]:     <os version="Chateau" platform="CoreOS" sp="1185.3.0_x86_64"></os>
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]:     <app appid="{e96281a6-d1af-4bde-9a0a-97b76e56dc57}" version="1185.3.0" track="stable" bootid="{a5ae9efe-11d2-4850-a29d-2f5da6ec2673}" oem="" oemversion="" alephversion="1185.3.0" machineid="806d28d1d39c45fdbeab2df0aa203da9" lang="en-US" board="amd64-usr" hardware_class="" delta_okay="false" >
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]:         <ping active="1"></ping>
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]:         <updatecheck></updatecheck>
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]:         <event eventtype="3" eventresult="2" previousversion=""></event>
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]:     </app>
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: </request>
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.103039 32226 libcurl_http_fetcher.cc:48] Starting/Resuming transfer
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.107463 32226 libcurl_http_fetcher.cc:164] Setting up curl options for HTTPS
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.164806 32226 libcurl_http_fetcher.cc:427] Setting up timeout source: 1 seconds.
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.539963 32226 libcurl_http_fetcher.cc:240] HTTP response code: 200
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.542742 32226 libcurl_http_fetcher.cc:297] Transfer completed (200), 267 bytes downloaded
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.542783 32226 omaha_request_action.cc:563] Omaha request response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: <response protocol="3.0" server="update.core-os.net">
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]:  <daystart elapsed_seconds="0"></daystart>
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]:  <app appid="e96281a6-d1af-4bde-9a0a-97b76e56dc57" status="ok">
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]:   <updatecheck status="noupdate"></updatecheck>
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]:  </app>
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: </response>
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.543097 32226 omaha_request_action.cc:383] No update.
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.543140 32226 action_processor.cc:82] ActionProcessor::ActionComplete: finished OmahaRequestAction, starting OmahaResponseHandlerAction
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.543157 32226 omaha_response_handler_action.cc:36] There are no updates. Aborting.
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.543175 32226 action_processor.cc:68] ActionProcessor::ActionComplete: OmahaResponseHandlerAction action failed. Aborting processing.
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.543189 32226 action_processor.cc:73] ActionProcessor::ActionComplete: finished last action of type OmahaResponseHandlerAction
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.543201 32226 update_attempter.cc:280] Processing Done.
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.543233 32226 update_attempter.cc:313] No update.
Feb 16 23:16:35 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:16:35.543265 32226 update_check_scheduler.cc:82] Next update check in 47m37s
```

And here's the same log file, right after I ran `update_engine_client -check_for_update`:

```
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:27:11.093904 32226 dbus_service.cc:57] Attempting interactive update
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:27:11.093967 32226 update_attempter.cc:253] New update check requested
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:27:11.095021 32226 omaha_request_params.cc:58] Current group set to stable
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:27:11.095325 32226 update_attempter.cc:465] Already updated boot flags. Skipping.
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:27:11.095361 32226 update_attempter.cc:608] Scheduling an action processor start.
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:27:11.095469 32226 action_processor.cc:36] ActionProcessor::StartProcessing: OmahaRequestAction
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:27:11.095847 32226 omaha_request_action.cc:245] Posting an Omaha request to https://public.update.core-os.net/v1/update/
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:27:11.095887 32226 omaha_request_action.cc:246] Request: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: <request protocol="3.0" version="CoreOSUpdateEngine-0.1.0.0" updaterversion="CoreOSUpdateEngine-0.1.0.0" installsource="ondemandupdate" ismachine="1">
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:     <os version="Chateau" platform="CoreOS" sp="1185.3.0_x86_64"></os>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:     <app appid="{e96281a6-d1af-4bde-9a0a-97b76e56dc57}" version="1185.3.0" track="stable" bootid="{a5ae9efe-11d2-4850-a29d-2f5da6ec2673}" oem="" oemversion="" alephversion="1185.3.0" machineid="806d28d1d39c45fdbeab2df0aa203da9" lang="en-US" board="amd64-usr" hardware_class="" delta_okay="false" >
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:         <ping active="1"></ping>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:         <updatecheck></updatecheck>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:         <event eventtype="3" eventresult="2" previousversion=""></event>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:     </app>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: </request>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:27:11.095916 32226 libcurl_http_fetcher.cc:48] Starting/Resuming transfer
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:27:11.096164 32226 libcurl_http_fetcher.cc:164] Setting up curl options for HTTPS
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:27:11.179698 32226 libcurl_http_fetcher.cc:427] Setting up timeout source: 1 seconds.
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:27:11.604357 32226 libcurl_http_fetcher.cc:240] HTTP response code: 200
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:27:11.610756 32226 libcurl_http_fetcher.cc:297] Transfer completed (200), 767 bytes downloaded
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:27:11.610851 32226 omaha_request_action.cc:563] Omaha request response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: <response protocol="3.0" server="update.core-os.net">
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:  <daystart elapsed_seconds="0"></daystart>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:  <app appid="e96281a6-d1af-4bde-9a0a-97b76e56dc57" status="ok">
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:   <updatecheck status="ok">
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:    <urls>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:     <url codebase="https://update.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/1235.9.0/"></url>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:    </urls>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:    <manifest version="1235.9.0">
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:     <packages>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:      <package hash="QP7VzgChmbSzhcrcG1ZaG0KkhB8=" name="update.gz" size="264914273" required="false"></package>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:     </packages>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:     <actions>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:      <action event="postinstall" ChromeOSVersion="" sha256="BmH7OF/zrM/i69mJqa7V6O6RPqAzWcOubldp9ik5lKo=" needsadmin="false" IsDelta="false" DisablePayloadBackoff="true"></action>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:     </actions>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:    </manifest>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:   </updatecheck>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]:  </app>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: </response>
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:27:11.611179 32226 omaha_request_action.cc:416] Found 1 url(s)
Feb 16 23:27:11 kore6 update_engine[32226]: I0216 23:27:11.611270 32226 omaha_request_action.cc:452] Processing first of 1 package(s)
```

It looks like both requests are identical, but the responses are different. What's going on here?